# execute sql query in php doesn't work ,but the query work in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

i have my database sql query file and i wanna run it in php by the code below

```
$query = file_get_contents('./sqlquery.txt');
print $query;
$conn->query($query);
```

but it return this error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ads` ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `ur' at line 2
```

i copied the print output in to the phpmyadmin and everything work well, what's wrong here?

my sql query is the this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ads`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ads` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `path` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `width` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `height` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `priority` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `adsalter` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `adstitle` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `comment`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(120) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `comment` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `contentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `parentid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `haschild` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `visible` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `files`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `files` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `size` int(14) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `newsid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `frgpss`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `frgpss` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(31) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(27) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` int(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `news`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `titrimage` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `titr` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `titralter` varchar(160) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `newsshurt` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `text` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `keywords` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `branch` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(160) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `visible` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `visited` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `titrtitle` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `signup`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `signup` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `family` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `picture` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `userregistereddate` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `key` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `userphoto` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `usergroup` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `ipaddress` text NOT NULL,
  `telnumber` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

Comment: Post your mysql query?

Comment: Please show the content of your file.

Comment: Have you tried running the code directly in a php page instead of calling it in from a text file?

Comment: Its failing the first line (even though it says line 2). You need to reference the database and the table like 'mydb'.'ads' rather than just 'ads'

Comment: What API are you using? `mysql`, `mysqli` or `pdo_mysql`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're executing multiple queries here, it won't work simply, I'm pretty sure that in `query` function(`$conn->query($query);`) you're using `mysql_query()` or `mysqli_query()`, but you'll have to do is to use `mysqli_multi_query()` instead. Have a look here at [docx](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

```
$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db) OR die(mysqli_error($con));
$query = file_get_contents('./sqlquery.txt');
mysqli_multi_query($con, $query);
mysqli_close($con);
```

Hope this will help you

**Note**: Assuming that all queries are working fine while executing in `PHPMyAdmin`.